# Удаление из std::list

Tags: c++

Нужно удалить элемент из `std::list`по итератору. Стандарт `С++11` и выше не используется. То есть имеется только функция `iterator std::list::erase( iterator first, iterator last );`

Если я сделаю так, то элемент не удалиться:

```
void func(std::list<int>& l, std::list<int>::iterator it)
{
    l.erase(it, ++it);
}
```

А если так, то все работает:

```
void func(std::list<int>& l, std::list<int>::iterator it)
{
    std::list<int>::iterator it2 = it;
    std::advance(it2, 1);
    l.erase(it, it2);
}
```

Почему? Ведь в `erase` в обоих случаях передаются одинаковые итераторы. Есть ли какой способ удалить один элемент из списка без лишних действий?

Comment: Вроде, до С++11 функция std::list::erase() могла принимать один итератор, который надо удалить.

Comment: http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase здесь сказано что такая возможность добавилась только в `C++11`

Comment: Во-первых, не ясно, почему вы решили,  что "в обоих случаях передаются одинаковые итераторы". Во-вторых, не ясно, почему вы решили, что до С++11 не было удаления по одному итератору.

Comment: @Rikitikitavi: Там сказано, что в С++11 произошел переход на константные итераторы. О том, что возможность удалять по одному итератору появилась в С++11 там ничего не сказано.

Comment: Да, действительно невнимательно посмотрел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с неопределённым поведением.

Дело в том, что компилятор имеет право вычислять значения аргументов функции в любом порядке. Так что в первом случае он может сначала вычислить и подставить значение второго аргумента (`++it`), и только потом — первого (`it`).

Во втором же случае значение `it2` вычисляется гарантировано до его использования в строке `l.erase(it, it2);` благодаря (грубо говоря) наличию точки с запятой.

Всё это является следствием работы механизма *точек следования*. Подробнее о нём можно почитать, например, в [статье «Точки следования (sequence points)» в блоге «Алёна C++»](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/11/sequence-points.html).

Comment: Нет уже никаких точек следования в современном c++.

Comment: @alexolut, знаю. Но вопрошающий написал: `Стандарт С++11 и выше не используется`.

Comment: Вот оно что, а то я русскую `С` не распарсил как `C`. Хотя тут много кто на странице этим грешит.

Answer (score 2):

Порядок вычисления и передачи аргументов в функции не определен. Т.е. компилятор может, например, сначала вычислить `++i`, а потом передавать значение.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


void f(int a, int b)
{
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 3;
    f(i,++i);
}
```

здесь, при том, что вы ожидаете `3 4`, реально может быть `4 4` - и не только может, но и VC++, и [GCC](https://ideone.com/5eJnVT) именно такой результат и дают.

P.S. См. понятие "[точка следования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)".